# Rendering validation errors in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

In a model say *Task*, I have following validation

```
 validates_presence_of :subject, :project, :user, :status
```

How do I render error messages for these validations using some other controller.

Inside CustomController I am using,

```
Task.create(hash)
```

passing nil values in hash gives following error,

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in CustomController#create

 Validation failed: Subject can't be blank
```

Code in the controller's create action

```
@task = Task.create(hash)
if @task.valid?
   flash[:notice] = l(:notice_successful_update)
else
    flash[:error] = "<ul>" + @task.errors.full_messages.map{|o| "<li>" + o + "</li>" }.join("") + "</ul>"
end
redirect_to :back
```

How to render error messages to user.

Task model is already built and it renders proper messages. i want to use its functionalities from a plugin.

Comment: you are also saving it twice in this create action. create will save it, and then you save it again.

Comment: oh! thnx for bringing it to notice.

Comment: @stellard, updated the post with the solution that worked for me. i guess this is not a bad approach. comments please?

Comment: I definitely would not put any html in the controller. This should be in the views, just the message text should be in the controller. It doesn't follow rails conventions, but without getting into more details, its generally ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <% if @task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you could turn this into a helper to replicate the old  error_messages_for functionality

Comment: okay. i will give this a try. i wanted to use 'error_messages_for' because the i am working on redmine plugins and redmine seems to use 'error_messages_for'.

Comment: `error_messages_for` is available. But you have to use this gem: https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form

Comment: @stellard, I tried your solution, but i am still getting above error ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in CustomController#create   Validation failed: Subject can't be blank

Comment: is it because i am calling Create method from other(i.e not taskscontroller) controller?

Comment: Are you using the create! method? That will raise an exception. Use create which will not raise a validation error and fall through to your view to render to the user.

Comment: i changed it to create instead of create! but instead of getting validation errors i get successful update flash. please check the updated code in the post

Comment: i will update the post with the code that worked for me. your pointers/hints helped me. thnx

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about showing errors on the edit-page (i.e.: in the form), then consider usage of the [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem. It'll show errors for you without a line of coding. Just replace `form_for` with `simple_form_for` and the magic will begin...

Comment: can you suggest some other solution? that doesnt require installing gem

Comment: what i have posted is what error messages for does. it was removed in rails 3

Comment: @stellard, I know about this. I just don't see any alternatives for gems. And `error_messages_for` wasn't just removed but was placed into a separate gem (https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form). So I think the author is doomed to use gems unless he wants headache while building forms.

Comment: @jdoe Doomed is pretty extreme I think... One could easily turn what I posted into a helper and use that on all their forms. They would also be able to customise the styling as well, which is more difficult if a gem is used.

Comment: @stellard, agreed to your last comment.

Comment: @jdoe, +1 for suggesting an alternative